# Minecraft problem with command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a simple one command but it keeps saying "data tag parsing failed".

What is wrong with my command?

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~
{
Block:wool,Time:1,Passengers:
{
[id:falling_block,Time:1,Block:command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:
{
auto:1,Command:/scoreboard objectives add tp trigger
}
,Passengers:
{
[
id:falling_block,Time:1,Block;command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:
{
auto:1,Command:/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar tp
}
,Passengers:
{
[
id:falling_block,Time:1,Block:command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:
{
Command:/scoreboard players set @a tp 0
}
]
}
]
}
]
}
}
```

https://pastebin.com/GsjfXNw3

I tried using notepad++, and I already re-wrote it 5 times.

Comment: Is `Data tag parsing failed` the only error you get?

Comment: @JacquesMarais Can't tell if a real burn or a serious question.

Comment: @LittleHelper The reason I am asking is because usually it will say `Data tag parsing failed at (etc...)`.

Answer (score 0):

while I don't know why its only summoning the falling wool block with no passengers, I got it to run at least

EDIT: fixed the command, had a few errors here and there, but I got it to work

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ 
{
Block:wool,Time:1,Passengers:
[
1:{
id:falling_block,Time:1,Block:command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:
{
auto:1,Command:"/scoreboard objectives add tp trigger"
},
Passengers:
[
1:{
id:falling_block,Time:1,Block:command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:
{
auto:1,Command:"/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar tp"
},
Passengers:
[
1:{
id:falling_block,Time:1,Block:command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:
{
Command:"/scoreboard players set @a tp 0"
}
}
]
}
]
}
]
}
```

main changes: `Passengers` uses `[]` with `x:{}` inside, not the other way around. Note: `x` is the passenger number.

`Command` tag needs double quotes.